# SSRS: Full Group Header with subgroups

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working in a SSRS report and I have a dataset like this:

| Client Id | Order Nº | Product Code | Quantity | Unit Price | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A001 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | A002 | 2 | 7 | 14 |
| 1 | 2 | A001 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | 2 | A003 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | A001 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | B001 | 100 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 3 | C001 | 9 | 9 | 81 |
| 2 | 4 | B002 | 17 | 2 | 34 |
| 2 | 4 | A003 | 1 | 3 | 3 |

I need the report to look like this:

[image: Desired report output]

The closer I was able to reach is this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The problem is that I can't merge all the cells in the header row, the first column remains isolated for the "Order" subgroup.

Any idea if that is possible somehow?

Maybe a List for the Clients and then a table with the orders? Is it possible to link/filter the table based in a group within the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily. If you used the wizard to create the report then I generally advise against this as it takes long to fix them than it does to build them from scratch.

Anyway, add a table, then drag the Order, Product, Qty, Price and Total fields onto it. Then on the "details" rowgroup, right-click and add a parent group, choose client as the grouping field and check the header option.

On the newly created row, right-click and insert a new row "inside group". Delete eth new column that was created (choose column only if prompted). Now you will have two header rows and you can merge the top one and set the client ID expression. Copy the column headers from the existing headers and then delete the row you copied them from.

Here's a 1 minute gif to show you how I did it..  The only thing I didn't do was remove the very top row, as I forgot !

You can right-click the gif and "open in new tab" then zoom in to make it easier to see.

[image]

---

Edit after OP update:

---

If you need to group by order as well, you could add a group by order between the detail and client groups, delete the generated column and then set `Hide Duplicates` property of the orderNo textbox to the name o fthe OrderGroup. Note that you will not be able to merge the order number vertically, it will just show on the first row. It will then look like this.

[image]

Here's the design...
[image]

The only other alternative would be to create a subreport that does the Order level part, this report would need to accept an order number as a parameter and the dataset queries adjusted to return details for that single order. Then create a master report with a dataset that returns a list of ClientIDs. Add a table with two detail rows. Top row with have "Client iD 1" etc like before. On the second row, insert a subreport and set the subreport property to the report you created that takes a client id, set the parameter for the subreport to be the clientid from your dataset.

If this does not help, let me know and I'll dig out a similar answer I wrote a while back (just no time to look for it now)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed demonstration. Unfortunately  that is not what I need. Besides grouping by Client, as you did in the demo, I need to group by order number.